# Http get json into string

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-7, indy, idhttp

I'm trying to get json response via HTTP GET method to a string but all I got is that: [image]

I'm using a code like that:

```
memo1.Text:= idhttp1.Get('http://blabla.com/bla.php');
```

it returns json data. i need to get that json response to memo1.

How can I do that?

Comment: Check the encoding of the text that you receive (should be in the headers somewhere) and apply the appropriate translation/conversion, ie UTF-8 to Ansi as you are using a non-Unicode Delphi. Searching for these terms should bring up plenty of examples.

Comment: @MarjanVenema: The overloaded version of `TIdHTTP.Get()` that returns a String already does exactly that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution. That code works perfect.

```
function GetURLAsString(aURL: string): string;
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  lStream: TStringStream;
begin
  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  lStream := TStringStream.Create(Result);
  try
    lHTTP.Get(aURL, lStream);
    lStream.Position := 0;
    Result := lStream.ReadString(lStream.Size);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(lHTTP);
    FreeAndNil(lStream);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: there's a way to suppress the dialog errors and get the errors as text? it you try to `GetURLAsString('http://google.com')` a dialog pops `301 moved permanently`

Answer (score 2):

Try a newer version of Indy, Indy still supports non-Unicode Delphi.

The Indy TIdHTTP Get should automatially convert UTF-8 to Ansi (with limitations):

> Internally, TIdHTTP.Get() decodes the server's UTF-8 data to Unicode,
>   and then converts that to Ansi when returning it as an AnsiString in
>   pre-2009 versions. That AnsiString uses the OS's default Ansi
>   codepage, so yes, there is potential for data loss if the OS's current
>   language does not support the Unicode characters being used by the
>   server.
>   http://forums2.atozed.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=3011